# Form is not submitting due to JavaScript validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have created a HTML form, but my form entries are not submitting due to my JavaScript form validation. Here is my HTML and JavaScript:

```js
jQuery("#template-jobform").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    jQuery('.form-process').fadeIn();
    jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
      success: function() {
        /*jQuery('.form-process').fadeOut();
        jQuery(form).find('.sm-form-control').val('');
        jQuery('#job-form-result').attr('data-notify-msg', jQuery('#job-form-result').html()).html('');
        SEMICOLON.widget.notifications(jQuery('#job-form-result'));*/
        //target: '#job-form-result',

        if (data.indexOf("ocation:") > 0) {
          window.location = data.replace("Location:", "");
        } else {
          $('#job-form-result').html(data)
          $('.form-process').fadeOut();
          jQuery(form).find('.sm-form-control').val('');
          jQuery('#job-form-result').attr('data-notify-msg', jQuery('#job-form-result').html()).html('');
          SEMICOLON.widget.notifications(jQuery('#job-form-result'));
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form action="include/jobs.php" id="template-jobform" name="template-jobform" method="post" role="form">

  <div class="form-process"></div>

  <div class="col_half">
    <label for="template-jobform-fname">First Name <small>*</small>
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="template-jobform-fname" name="template-jobform-fname" value="" class="sm-form-control required" />
  </div>

  <div class="col_half col_last">
    <label for="template-jobform-lname">Last Name <small>*</small>
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="template-jobform-lname" name="template-jobform-lname" value="" class="sm-form-control required" />
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="col_full">
    <label for="template-jobform-email">Email <small>*</small>
    </label>
    <input type="email" id="template-jobform-email" name="template-jobform-email" value="" class="required email sm-form-control" />
  </div>

  <div class="col_half">
    <label for="template-jobform-age">Age <small>*</small>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="template-jobform-age" id="template-jobform-age" value="" size="22" tabindex="4" class="sm-form-control required" />
  </div>

  <div class="col_half col_last">
    <label for="template-jobform-city">City <small>*</small>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="template-jobform-city" id="template-jobform-city" value="" size="22" tabindex="5" class="sm-form-control required" />
  </div>

  <div class="col_full">
    <label for="template-jobform-application">Application <small>*</small>
    </label>
    <textarea name="template-jobform-application" id="template-jobform-application" rows="6" tabindex="11" class="sm-form-control required"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="col_full">
    <button class="button button-3d button-large btn-block nomargin" name="template-jobform-apply" type="submit" value="apply">Send Application</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

The page loads indefinitely after clicking on the "send application" button due to this script.

Comment: Any errors in the `console`? Maybe your response thrown an error so the `success` function is not firing.

Comment: could you please help with alternative validation ?

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is with the validation plugin but with your server response. Do you get any errors in the console?